# Java OO Design: why choose to pass a class type over an interface or object?

Tags: java, oop, generics, types, instantiation

I have seen the use of passing class types as parameters more and more. I am wondering what are the reasons why someone would design an application to use a class type over an interface or an object.

Simply why:

```
someFunction(someclass.class);
```

Over:

```
someFunction(new someclass());
```

where some class is a concrete object implementing someInterface.

Comment: Because one creates an instance of `someclass`, the other does not. It is very often used when dealing with generics and mapping. Note that `someclass.class` is an instance as well, an instance of `Class`.

Comment: `new someclass()` is a call to a constructor. Nobody assures you that that constructor is public or that it even exists (it could require a parameter). Why would you create an instance of a class when you just need the type?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, explicitly speaking but you can use the class type to instantiate someclass.  So my question stands why pass the class type and not the class, or some interface representation of the class? What are the benefits of passing the .class?

Comment: @Oneiros That is sort of my question.  Why would you need only the type in the first place?  Traditionally speaking I have never needed just the class type. I have always needed the concrete class.

Comment: If you posted the code and/or the javadoc of someFunction, we could explain why it has that signature. Without it, all we can do is guess.

Comment: What do you mean by “concrete class”? By using `new` you are passing an instance of a class, not the class itself. The `.class` is the only way to statically identify a class (Generics could be another way)

Comment: @Onerios  By concrete class I mean actual object instance (new someclass()) vs the class type (someclass.class).  By why would you need to statically identify a class if they pass the class to you?  Even then, could you just get the class type from the class itself.

Comment: @JB Nizet There is not code or javadoc for someFunction.  They could be any function. There are lots of examples Spring framework you initialize the application by calling SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);  In android you can instantiate Fragments and such using similar notations.  Why choose these options over calling SpringApplication.run(this, args); or something

Comment: Then pick one of those examples, and ask about it.

Comment: @JB Nizet it is not about those examples. It is a design question. What are the benefits of passing the Class type over the actual instantiated object of that class?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. It's the same thing as "what is the benefit in passing a String to a method rather than an int". You pass a String when the method needs a String to do its job, and you pass an int when the method needs an int to do its job. Without knowing what the job of the method is, we can't say why it needs a String rather than an int.

Comment: That is one what of thinking sure. But I think you are missing the point. And that is ok

Comment: No, *he* is not missing the point, *you* are. You cannot ask extremely general question and expect good answers. The only reasonably answer was given after you had chosen one specific example.

Comment: Nope, sorry @luk2302  I am not missing anything.  And for you to stick your nose in only illustrates the fact you are also missing something. The only reasonable answer used the example given it did not require it. But hey good for you for being a donkey up votes for you

Comment: Simply *facepalm*. Please take out suggestion for future questions to fellow programmers both on SO and in person. Your statement is simply wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take an example from the comments: why `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);` instead of `SpringApplication.run(this, args);`?

I haven't actually used Spring so I'm not certain this is a correct description of how Spring invokes dependency injection, but it should serve to answer the question regardless.

To start with, this method is typically called from `main`. More to the point, from `public static void main`. That's a `static` method, and `this` doesn't exist in those. So it would have to be `SpringApplication.run(new Application(), args);` instead.

But what if the constructor of `Application` looks like `public Application(Something dependency1, AnotherThing dependency2, SomethingElse dependency3)`? You'd have to make each of those dependency objects first, and they might have their own dependencies too. You'd end up with this giant sequence of dozens of lines of creating new objects and passing them to the constructors of more new objects.

`SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);` is a single short line no matter what the `Application` constructor looks like, and it is specifically designed to figure out and make all those dozens of required objects for you. It looks at `Application`'s constructor and sees that list of three arguments, looks at those classes, finds their constructors, looks at those constructors' arguments lists, etc., until it has enough information to put the whole big mess together for you. All from one short method call. Requiring that you pass an already-made instance of `Application` rather than the class would negate the point of this, and the class is all it actually needs.

There are a great many other things that can be done with a class where using an instance instead would be unnecessary or even actually break the desired functionality, this is just one example of that.